# How to RegEx validate a string of digits within the range of 100000 - 999999999?

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my attempt, seems to work from testing, any regex pros have any better suggestion or see any problem with this?

`^([1-9]|[1-9]\d|[1-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d\d\d)(\d{5})$`

Comment: The first level factoring is this `1\d{5}|[2-9]\d{5}|[1-9]\d{6,8}` the second level is this `[1-9]\d{5}|[1-9]\d{6,8}` the third level is this `[1-9]\d{5,8}`

Comment: If `str` is your string and `n1..n2` is the desired range you could write `(Integer(str) rescue nil)&.between?(n1, n2)`. `n1` (`n2`) need not be a power of 10 (power of 10 less one). `&` is Ruby's recently-introduced (v2,3) [Safe Navigation Operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/). Note (Integer("0x7a") rescue nil)&.between?(100, 200) #=> true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unify all cases into one by giving minimum and maximum amounts of digits:

```
^[1-9]\d{5,8}$
```

Comment: Of course. Unsure why I was complicating things with my attempt !

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to check the string, I believe this is more expressive:

```
(100000..999999999).cover?(input[/\A\d+\z/].to_i)
```